# How to get user_likes after firebaseauth-ui call is successful with user_likes permission approved on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am working on a login flow with FirebaseUI for web.
Facebook provider is invoked with scope(permission) user_likes.
After user approves the app and permissions, login is successful.

However, I am now wondering how to retrieve the user_likes via a graph API call to facebook directly.
Essentially, where to retrieve the required parameters from successful firebase auth so as to make a successful graph api retrieving user_likes list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the facebook auth credential from the signInSuccess callback. You can then use the OAuth credential to query the facebook api:

```
'callbacks': {
      'signInSuccess': function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
        // Do something.
        // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
        // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
        // Credential is in credential.accessToken
        return false;
      }
    }
```